# Set focus to UITabBarItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` with several tab bar items in it. The first tab bar item has a view called `A` and it has a button called `Click` . When i click on that button the view will navigate to another view. (Since this tab has a `UINavigationController` the view will get a Back button).

Now this view will have a button, where when i click on it, i should navigate to the 2nd TabItem. (Meaning the `UITabBarItem` should be set focus, and there should not be a Back button (as in a navigation controller))

Note :

When the user clicks on the button, i used the following code to navigate to the other view of another UITabBarItem. Then the 2nd tab bar item is not set focused, and the back button from the navigation controller is also seen.

```
SelectSiteViewController *siteViewController =
[[SelectSiteViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SelectSiteViewController"
                                           bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:siteViewController
                                     animated:YES];
```

Hope i made my question clear. How can i code this?

Comment: you are pushing a view controller **onto** the navigation stack...the back button is there to let the user get back. But you are not changing the active tab bar item, so no focus, no second view controller, and a back button. You are probably looking for changing the [selectedViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) property of the `UITabBarController`.

Comment: I found this by googling; is this correct `self.tabBarController.selectedViewController 
    = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];`

Comment: It should...if `2` is the index of what you want.. Did you test ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, you want to remove the current view controller from the navigation task and select the second tab in the tab bar controller.

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = self.navigationController;
[navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[navigationController.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[myTabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

Comment: This will only set focus to the tabbaritem, What should i do to the Back button in the navigation bar ?

Comment: [self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:nil];